# Remove "<div class="q-field__bottom row ..." in q-input (Quasar Framework)

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, user-interface, rendering, quasar-framework

I used the **q-input** with the code below (I used Quasar v2.0.4):

```html
<q-input
  filled
  outlined
  square
  dense
  clearable
  v-model="vModel"
  :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0)]"
/>
```

Then, **after redered on a browser**, the code below was added:

```html
<div class="q-field__bottom row items-start q-field__bottom--animated">...</div>
```

This is the full code of the **q-input** rendered on **Google Chrome** (The code above is shown in pink):

[image]

Actually, the code **"<div class="q-field__bottom row ..."** sometimes bothers my **UI(User Interface)** so I really want to remove the code. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is one property to remove that bottom space `hide-bottom-space`.

```html
<q-input
  hide-bottom-space // Here
  filled
  outlined
  square
  dense
  clearable
  v-model="vModel"
  :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0)]"
/>
```

**hide-bottom-space** - Do not reserve space for hint/error/counter anymore when these are not used; As a result, it also disables the animation for those; It also allows the hint/error area to stretch vertically based on its content

Answer (score 0):

Add this **CSS** code below which removes the code **"<div class="q-field__bottom row ..."** and doesn't bother your **UI(User Interface)** at all:

```css
.q-field__bottom {
  display: none;
}
```

Actually, the part of your code below adds or makes the code **"<div class="q-field__bottom row ..."**:

```js
:rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0)]"
```

In addition, **hide-bottom-space** also can remove the code **"<div class="q-field__bottom row ..."**.

```html
<q-input
  hide-bottom-space // Here
  filled
  outlined
  square
  dense
  clearable
  v-model="vModel"
  :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0)]"
/>
```

However, in this case of **hide-bottom-space**, if there is an input error, almost the same code below as **"<div class="q-field__bottom row ..."** is added different from the **CSS** code which doesn't bother **UI(User Interface)** at all.

```html
<div class="q-field__bottom row items-start q-field__bottom--state">...</div>
```

So if you don't want any bother for your **UI**, you better use the **CSS** code on the top of the post.